# Звідки пішов вислів "марна праця хлібороба"?

Tags: фразеологізми

Шукаю походження вислову *марна праця хлібороба*. У мережі є лише декілька траплянь і це вже вжитки. Про походження нічого не можу знайти.

Answer (score 0):

## Марна праця

Фразеологізм **"марна праця"** означає виконання якоїсь безглуздої марної роботи і вживається, коли спостерігач бачить якусь беззмістовну діяльність, що не приносить жодної користі або результату.

В українській мові існує багато семантично тотожних фразеологізмів із різноманітним лексичним забарвленням, як от **"товкти воду у ступі"**, **"гнути спину"**, **"тягти на шиї"**, **"рвати руки, сраку"**. Та найвідоміший посеред інших фразеологізм **"[сизіфова праця](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%96%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%84)"**. Він бере свій початок ще з міфів Давньої Греції.

Щодо походження вислову **"марна праця хлібороба"**, схоже що  першоджерелом є вірш.

**[Залізо й глина – несумісні речі](http://www.poetryclub.com.ua/printpoem.php?id=697196)**

```
Залізо й глина – несумісні речі;
Але стоїть на тому істукан,
Що вперто вони сплавлені у печі,
Аби втягнути людство в певний стан

Безбожної структури цього світу,
Подвійних трендів влади гендлярів.
Добро і зло з Старого Заповіту -
Улюблене кайло каменярів,

Котрі заклали сплав цей в піраміду
Всесвітнього концтабору для душ
З наклейкою «сади Семираміди»,
Породження васалів і чинуш. 

Ісус є рішенням всіх негараздів
На цій, в крові потопленій землі,
Бо Він є Господом царів та газдів,
Йому покірні боги й королі.

І саме Він є Істина народам,
Спаситель людства і Верховний Цар.
Його створіння – Всесвіт і природа,
Він людям дав життя безцінний дар!

Без Нього є безплідною утроба,
Трава без цвіту, без води моря;
Без Нього марна праця хлібороба
І стовпчики поета-віршаря.

Не треба плавити залізо в глину,
А в правду лити домішки брехні!
Тримайся істини аж до загину,
Гартуючи її вогнем борні.
                              23.10.2016
```

Comment: Я знаходжу допис на форумі від 12 січня 2016 року, де ця фраза вже присутня. Тому не думаю, що цей вірш це першоджерело.

Comment: В пошуку інфи справді нуль. Думаю, що вислів "марна праця хлібороба" може вживатись у сенсі "не варте людського життя".